# How to get consolidated results from ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Iusdds?p=preview).

```
<div ng-repeat="subCategory in subCategorys | filter:{tags:tag}:true | orderBy:'id'">
      {{subCategory.id}} {{subCategory.name}} {{subCategory.tags}}
      <br/><br/>
      You are now seeing details of <span ng-init="subCats = subCats + ' '  + subCategory.name">{{subCats}}</span>
    </div>
```

This HTML page shows a filtered result from an object. However, I want to display a consolidated result of the names after "You are now seeing details of" like for example, "You are now seeing details of jim tom". This consolidated list should appear after the element which has ng-repeat directive.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1RlRHXgpRFzRO4CmKWyr?p=preview) for you.

Please try to make your example plunker way more reduced to the specific problem in the future as this helps us to help you.

First I added the search binding as filter to the ng-repeat to make the filter workable:

```
<div ng-repeat="subCategory in subCategorys | filter:{tags:tag}:true | filter:{id:search} | orderBy:'id'">
```

To avoid executing the filter twice you can save the filter result directly into a scope variable by simply assinging it (in my example to subCategorysFilter):

```
<div ng-repeat="subCategory in subCategorysFilter = (subCategorys | filter:{tags:tag}:true | filter:{id:search} | orderBy:'id')">
```

I further changed your `getAllFilteredNames()` method to take a filter object as argument and made it loop through the results, build an array of the names and join them with a `,` as separation:

```
  $scope.getAllFilteredNames = function(filter){
    var names = [];
    angular.forEach(filter, function(element){
      names.push(element.name);
    });
    return names.join(", ");
  };
```

This is now called outside the ng-repeat directive:

```
You are now seeing details of {{getAllFilteredNames(subCategorysFilter)}}
```

Have fun!

---

### Update

Two possible solutions for getting a multilined output:

1 - You might change the line

```
<div>You are now seeing details of {{getAllFilteredNames(subCategorysFilter)}}</div>
```

to

```
<div>You are now seeing details of <span ng-bind-html="getAllFilteredNames(subCategorysFilter)"></span></div>
```

Then any html tags within the expression are compiled as html code. But there are meaningful reasons for angular disabling this feature by default. If your objects are editable by users you need to prevent them from breaking your design by escaping all html tags...

2 - But if you do not need to display the cosolidated information within a single string, you might simply use another ng-repeat combined with an `<ul>` like this:

```
<div>You are now seeing details of <br/>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="subCategory in subCategorysFilter">{{subCategoryName}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Just style your `li` accordingly to be displayed underneath each other and you're ready to go.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel :) . This works. Appreciate you updating my Plunker :)

Comment: I tried doing `return names.join(" <br/> ");` using `<br/>` instead of a comma (,) but it did not append a break in line it showed the text as '<br/>'. What am I missing here, if i want to add a line break?

Comment: The feature of inserting html markup through expressions is deactivated for safety reasons to prevent attackers from breaking your site. You can use ngbindhtml to enable the feature: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngbindhtml

Comment: But if you don't want to display the names in a single string anyway you could even remove the `getAllFilteredNames()` method and use another ng-repeat. I'll updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: The link above does not work,as they expect case sensitiive URIs at angularjs.org. this one should work: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in your HTML by moving your consolidated list outside of the ngRepeat and calling the filter again:

```
  <div ng-repeat="subCategory in subCategorys | filter:{tags:tag}:true | orderBy:'id'">
         {{subCategory.id}} {{subCategory.name}} {{subCategory.tags}}
         <br/><br/>
  </div>
  <div>
        You are now seeing details of 
        <span ng-repeat="subCategory in subCategorys | filter:{tags:tag}:true | orderBy:'id'">
                  {{subCategory.name}}&nbsp;
        </span>
  </div>
```

The drawback to this approach is that you are calling the filter twice. A better alternative would be to set up a $watch in your parent controller and invoke the $filter manually. I.e. Save the filtered results in a scope variable. The benefit is that the filter is called half as many times and the scope variables you set up are visible to the original list and the consolidated list.

```
app.controller('ParentController', function($scope, $filter) {
        $scope.subCategorys = [{...}];
        $scope.tag = {...};
        $scope.$watchCollection('subCategorys', function(newList){
               //if the collection changes, create a new tag 
               //reference that is a copy of the old one to trigger 
               //the tag watch listener
               if (newList)
                   $scope.tag = angular.copy($scope.tag);
        });
        $scope.$watch('tag', function(newTag){
               // if tag changes, apply the filter, 
               // and save the result to a scope variable
               if(newTag)
                    $scope.filteredList = $filter('filter')
                          ($scope.subCategories, { tags: newTag},  true);
        });

});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController">

  <div ng-repeat="subCategory in filteredList | orderBy:'id'">
         {{subCategory.id}} {{subCategory.name}} {{subCategory.tags}}
         <br/><br/>
  </div>
  <div>
        You are now seeing details of 
        <span ng-repeat="subCategory in filteredList | orderBy:'id'">
                  {{subCategory.name}}&nbsp;
        </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no way of doing that except for selecting the subCategory back. Fortunately, there is a pretty elegant 'angular' way of doing that. Add this to your controller:

```
$scope.getSubCatById = function(someId) {
  return $filter('filter')($scope.subCategorys, {id:someId})[0]; 
}
```

And then your html:

```
<div ng-repeat="subCategory in subCategorys | filter:{tags:tag}:true | orderBy:'id'">
      {{subCategory.id}} {{subCategory.name}} {{subCategory.tags}}
      <br/><br/>
      You are now seeing details of {{ getSubCatById(2).name }}
</div>
```

I hope I interpreted your question correctly.